# Calculate $\int_0^{2\pi} e^ {-i\theta}e^{e^{i\theta}} d\theta$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Calculate the integral:

> $$\int_0^{2\pi} e^ {-i\theta}e^{e^{i\theta}} \ \mathrm{d}\theta$$

I can't use directly substitution, so I am stuck with it as it is. I also can't seem to find how to use Cauchy-Goursat here with a suitable circle. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**
$$\int_0^{2\pi} e^ {-i\theta}e^{e^{i\theta}} d\theta =\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{e^{i\theta}}}{ (e^ {i\theta})^2}  e^ {i\theta} d\theta$$
Now use $z=e^{i \theta}$.

Comment: So, performing the substitution, we get $$\frac{1}{i} \int_{|z| = 1} \frac{e^{z}}{(z-0)^2} dz.$$ Since $z \mapsto e^z$ is entire, it is analytic on any disc containing the unit circle, so the Cauchy integral formula says $$\frac{1}{i} \int_{|z| = 1} \frac{e^{z}}{(z-0)^2} dz = \frac{1}{i} 2 \pi i \frac{d}{dz} \bigg|_{z=0} e^{z} = 2 \pi.$$ Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

**Another Hint**

$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-i\theta}e^{e^{i\theta}} \, \mathrm{d}\theta
= \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-i\theta}\left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{in\theta}}{n!} \right) \, \mathrm{d}\theta
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{i(n-1)\theta} \, \mathrm{d}\theta $$

by the uniform convergence.